# Example of a group in which intersection of all non-normal subgroups is non-trivial

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

What are some examples of a group in which intersection of all non-normal subgroups is non-trivial.

Do I consider abelian or Hamiltonian groups an example for this as they have only normal subgroups, so there does not exist any intersection of non-normal subgroups ? What are some other not so vacuous examples?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean? Do you want the intersection of every pair of non-normal subgroups to be non-trivial?

Comment: @Bungo Intersection of all non-normal subgroups

Answer (score 2):

In the group defined by the presentation $\langle x,y \mid x^3 = y^4 = 1, y^{-1}xy=x^{-1} \rangle$ (which is isomorphic to the subgroup of $\langle (1,2,3),(1,2)(4,5,6,7) \rangle$ of $S_7$), the only non-normal subgroups are the three Sylow $2$-subgroups, all conjugate to $\langle y \rangle$. Their intersection is the subgroup $\langle y^2 \rangle$ of order $2$.